# OpenCV approxPolyDP function parameters in Java

Tags: java, android, opencv, parameters

I have an ArrayList of points which are the corners of a rectangle. I want to use the next function in Java/Android. The problem is that there isn't a constructor like Mat(corners) in OpenCV for Android Library. How can i convert corners to MatOfPoint2f for this function?

```
approxPolyDP(cv::Mat(corners), approx, cv::arcLength(cv::Mat(corners), true) * 0.02, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is equivalent code for Point2d, if you have points of other type, change Point2d and Vec2d to appropriate type (e.g. Point2f and Vec2f for float).

```
vector<cv::Point2d> pts(10,Point2d(0,1)); // Your points
Mat m(pts.size(),1,CV_64FC2); // Your matrix
for(int i=0;i<pts.size();++i) // Assign points to matrix
{
    m.at<Vec2d>(i)[0]=pts[i].x;
    m.at<Vec2d>(i)[1]=pts[i].y;
}
```

Comment: The OP is asking for a Java solution.